# Что выбрать C++ или C#

Tags: c#, c++

Хотелось бы заняться созданием программ мой выбор пал на C++ и на C#.
Не знаю что и выбрать. Хотел бы спросить у вас дорогие хешкодовцы, что лучше выбрать. C C# я немного знаком, но имею представление хоть и не большое о нём. А что за зверь C++?

Comment: Если хотите, чтобы вам внятно ответили, опишите подробнее (значительно подробнее!), для чего вы будете использовать этот язык.

Как минимум:

— Для каких платформ и ОСей? (десктопные, мобильные, браузерные, микроконтроллеры и тп)

— Какого плана программы? (корпоративные, потребительские, системные утилиты, игры и тп)

— Зачем писать? (как хобби, как работу, как помощь своей работе, как фрилансер)

Comment: Если для работы — зависит от требований. (Смотрите комментарий выше.) А вообще, чем больше языков вы знаете, тем лучше.

Comment: Что выбирать-то, оба изучайте.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если для Вас программирование это что то новое, то начинайте с С (обычный С без каких то там ++ и #). Берите в руки терминал (да да устанавливайте Linux, это не шутка, привыкайте к хорошему), обычный блокнот, например, sublime text 2, книгу ["Язык программирования С"](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2480925/) и начинайте штудировать ее. Я сторонник того, что программист, даже пусть какой нибудь php developer просто обязан хоть немного, но все же понимать как все работает на низком уровне.

Так вот, вы проштудировали С и теперь думаете, что же дальше, а дальше дела обстоят так, если вы выбираете C#, то привязываетесь к одной единственной ОС Windows (пусть даже и есть какой то там Mono) и зависите от Microsoft. Большинство вакансий на C# это ASP.NET - веб, так что… тут сами думайте… По поводу книг, для начала лучше взять [Шилдта](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5532458/) он понятно описывает ООП, да и сам язык тоже, затем я бы вам предложил [Троелсен](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/19916784/), ну и на конец, когда вы уже будете хорошо плавать в C# и в программировании, можете почитать [Рихтера](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/7425674/), он уже описывает не язык C#, а платформу .NET. (Все книги посоветовал мой друг, который более менее шарит в .NET и C#).

Дальше у нас на очереди С++. <joke>Ну… что тут сказать, для чего С++, если есть С ?</joke> А по делу, на С++ хорош тем, что программист волен выбирать уровень абстракции, то есть в одной программе он может писать как на самом низком уровне (работать с памятью итд итп), так и на самом высоком (я надеюсь меня правильно поймут). На С++ можно писать относительно кроссплатформенные вещи, для этого существует [Qt](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt). По книгам могу посоветовать начать с [этого](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/7979735/), потом [Страуструп](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5600302/), ну это уже больше как справочник, затем Мейерс, Саттер и Александреску и, если вы все это будет подкреплять практикой, то будете многих людей разносить в щепки в плане С++.

Я бы вам еще посоветовал посмотреть в сторону Java, но тут уже выбор за вами. А вообще все эти языки лишь инструмент, кто бы что мне сейчас не стал доказывать, главное же иметь мозги, хороши ими пользовать, знать алгоритмы, даже не знать их наизусть, это как раз таки плохо, а просто понимать как они работают. По алгоритмам советовать наверное не нужно, просто берете [Кормена](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2429691/), но может это я уже загнул. Когда будете изучать С, а я все же думаю вы сделаете правильный выбор, можете зайти на http://codeforces.ru/ куча задачек, который заставляют пошевелить мозгами, так же есть [тимус](http://acm.timus.ru/), куча задач на любую сложность.

Answer (score 6):

Я в своё время выбрал C# и не пожалел, как по мне у него мне больше понравился синтаксис, мне на нём было проще сделать приложения, т.к он построен на .NET(хотя С++ тоже есть под .NET), но по шарпу(именно под .NET) я нашел больше курсов, уроков и книг. На С++ пробовал писать программы, но он мне тяжело дался. Так что совет попробуйте выучить понемногу каждый пописать на них и какой больше понравится на том и оставаться плюс надо ещё посмотреть для чего вы их учите, для себя или для работы.